# Парсер с ошибкой (Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out)

Tags: java, jsoup

Пишу простой парсер.
В зависимости от сайта, вылезает ошибка. Если сайт `https://`, то вроде все нормально. Если `http://`, то проблемы возникают в виде сообщений:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:571)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:548)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:235)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:224)
at parser1.main(parser1.java:14)
```

Сам код:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Example program to list links from a URL.
 */
public class parser1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://tinko.ru/").get();
        System.out.print(doc.select(".emet_index").text());
        Elements els = doc.select("a");
        for(Element link : els) {
            System.out.println(link.text());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: судя по ошибке, страницу не удаётся загрузить за какое-то время (30 или 60 секунд обычно).

Comment: Ещё проверьте, что ваш сайт вообще открывается

Comment: и пробуй еще `Jsoup.connect("https://tinko.ru/").timeout(100*1000).get(); `

Comment: этот сайт вообще не отвечает

Comment: Правильный адрес http://www.tinko.ru/, но он так же выдает ошибку. А в браузере открывается нормально. Таймаут тоже нге помог

Answer (score 1):

сайт без `www` перенаправляет на версию с `www`. сделайте так:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://tinko.ru/").followRedirects(true).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что правильный адрес страницы "http://www.tinko.ru/" и он не парсится ни в каком случае. Проверял. Те сайты которые смотрел и они http они не конектятся. А с https норм.

Comment: `и он не парсится ни в каком случае. Проверял` – как Вы проверяли?

Comment: ну из 1000 попыток ни одного конекта.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что Ваш сайт недоступен по `https`. Используйте `http`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.tinko.ru").get();
System.out.println(doc.html());
```

Результат:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200"> 
  <title>Торговый Дом ТИНКО — поставка технических средств безопасности</title> 
  ...
```